# Accessibility for a button that navigates

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a button that needs to perform some logic, and then redirect the user to a different route. What `aria` tags, or other accessibility modifications need to be made, so that the user knows they're about to go somewhere?

I know the best answer is "don't use a button for navigation," but logic has to happen before the navigation, so the alternative is an `<a href="" onClick=...>` which...maybe that's better (even though my linter really hates the idea).

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the [`link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_link_role) role on your button.

Comment: and change the aria value when you change your button on a different route